# How to Get Google Drive Files with out any credential in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I am able to get Google drive files in asp.net

but i want to show a my google drive data in my website.

for this what need to use?

I searched on Google and find a link which will general a Refresh token and auth. tokel for 1 hour

i don't know how to use that one.

please share some code to do this.

Please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: I also face the same issue.Did you get any solution yet?